# Windows phone Nested Listbox with setting the max items for the inner listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, listbox

i want to set the maximum items for the inner list box the code is similar to the following.

```
      <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="List" >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10" >
                            <ListBox>

                             </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

for example i want to set the maximum items in the inner listbox to 5,
is it possible to do it from Xaml with out using C#, if no,
how to do it from C# code.
thank you.